# sh command in python fails

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, sh

### I am a beginner in python. I got these scripts from IP vendor.

```
cmd = "sh compile_regression_vcs.sh"

try:
    self.agent.run_commands(cmd, pwd=self.agent.test_dir, extra_env=env)
except TestException as e:
    s = traceback.format_exc()
    serr = "there were errors:\n%s\n" % (s)
    self.logger.info(serr)
    raise TestException("Could not compile RTL")
except IOError as e:
    raise TestException("Could not compile RTL: %s" % str(e))
```

---

output looks like this:

```
TestException: command 'sh' generated 2 errors, aborting.
```

When i run sh command seperately without python, i donot get any errors. I donot understand why python gives an exception

Comment: Please format your code. Highlight it and click the `{}` button. You'll want to have it formatted decently before you paste it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
/bin/sh compile_regression_vcs.sh
```

Is compile_regression_vcs.sh in the current directory?

Answer (score 2):

The issue could mainly be the path for you shell and your shell script. 
It could also be that the environment that you are running in your shell maybe different from the one that you are using in your python script. Check this: extra_env=env

If you are still unable to zero in on issue you can debug further with following options:

You might want to use some debugging in your script to see the exact error.
Using sys.exc_info() would be a good option to see stack details.

you could use this piece of code in your exception block:

```
import sys
tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    lst = format_list(extract_stack())
    for l in lst: print l,
```

or you could just use:

```
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

much cleaner :)

Refer to: [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html),
[sys](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)

You can also run a python debugger to debug run_commands is executing as expected.
Simply put these lines of code in your try block and you will get into the interactive python debugger mode.

```
try:
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    self.agent.run_commands(cmd, pwd=self.agent.test_dir, extra_env=env)
```

you can later type help in python debugger mode to see all options available.
Refer: 
[pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb#module-pdb)

You could also use inspect module:
[inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#module-inspect)

Comment: The issue is that run_commands is a script which looks at the log file of the commands and look for the string 'error' in the 'command' log file. Incidentally the log file has a string 'error' as a file name even though nothing is wrong in the 'run'. The 'run_commands' script returns 1 or 0 if the string 'error' is found in the log file.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I love this site.